# Create Groups in a Table if they have similar sets of fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table

```
dept att1 
d1   a       
d2   a
d3   a
d3   c
d4   a
d4   b
d5   a
d5   b
```

I want to create logical groups from the above table as follows

```
group 1: d1,d2
group 2: d3
group 3: d4,d5
```

I will add a dept to a logical group if they have exact set matched in column att1.

Eg: d1 and d2 have a common value a.d3 has a but also additionally contains c.d4 and d5 has a and b forming a separate group. How to achieve this using sql

Comment: Can a department have the same attribute more than once? If d1 has 'a' twice and d2 has 'a' once, are they in the same group or not?

Comment: Please say exactly what Oracle database version you have. Please *always* give your version in all questions about the Oracle database. Don't you do this when you have Java questions?

Comment: yes it can.If d1 has a twice and d2 has a once it will fall under the same group.

Answer (score 2):

Kiran's answer uses the right approach: concatenate the ATT1 values by department, then group by the concatenated values. The problem is that `LISTAGG` cannot produce any string longer than a `VARCHAR2`, and you cannot `GROUP BY` any string longer than a `VARCHAR2`.

To overcome the `LISTAGG` limitation, use `XMLAGG`.

To overcome the `GROUP BY` limitation, group by a hash of the string, not the string itself. There is a very, very slight chance of a false positive. To reduce the chance of that, upgrade to a newer version of the database that uses a bigger hash.

```
select listagg(dept,',') within group(order by dept) depts
from (
  select dept,
    dbms_crypto.hash(
      xmlagg(xmlelement("a", att1) order by att1).getClobVal(),
      3
    ) att1_hash
  from (select distinct dept, att1 from t)
  group by dept
)
group by att1_hash;
```

Comment: thanks it works.i do not have access to the sys schemas which means i cannot use the hash functions.Are there any limitations if i do not use the hash function.

Comment: "Are there any limitations if i do not use the hash function": Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are using oracle 11g R2 then below mentioned solution should work

```
SELECT Listagg(dept, ',') 
         within GROUP (ORDER BY dept) AS att 
FROM   (SELECT dept, 
               Listagg(att1, ',') 
                 within GROUP (ORDER BY att1) AS att 
        FROM   test 
        GROUP  BY dept)A 
GROUP  BY A.att
```

kindly refer sql fiddle demo

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddef3/5/0

Comment: Hi this results in the following error SQL Error [1489] [72000]: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Comment: It seems that the issue is on production data due to large data volume. In that case you should write a cursor to aggregate the data.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the Oracle limits, you can identify all pairs of `dept`s that have exactly the same attributes.  Then use the min department name (or a ranking on it) as the group.

Assuming that the pairs are unique, the following generates the matching pairs:

```
with dn as (
      select dept, attr, count(*) over (partition by dept) as cnt
      from t
     )
select dn1.dept, dn2.dept
from dn dn1 join
     dn dn2
     on dn2.att1 = dn1.att1 and
        dn2.cnt = dn1.cnt
group by dn1.dept, dn2.dept, dn1.cnt
having count(*) = dn1.cnt  -- all match
```

Note that this keeps ALL pairs with the same `att1` values, so all `dept`s match themselves in this result.

For the final group assignment:

```
with dn as (
      select dept, attr, count(*) over (partition by dept) as cnt
      from t
     )
select dept1, min(dept2) as first_dept,
       dense_rank() over (order by min(dept2)) as grp_number
from (select dn1.dept as dept1, dn2.dept as dept2
      from dn dn1 join
           dn dn2
           on dn2.att1 = dn1.att1 and
              dn2.cnt = dn1.cnt
      group by dn1.dept, dn2.dept, dn1.cnt
      having count(*) = dn1.cnt
     ) dd
group by dept1;
```

In general, I prefer the `listagg()` approach.  But if that is not viable, this should also work.